# What is the proper way of using sessions/cookies in facebook app in python?

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, flask, facebook-apps

I am building a facebook app using python (Flask framework).

When I load up my app, apps.facebook.com/exampleapp I am getting my facebook ID from signed_request. However, my navigation did not work. For instance, if I clicked on a link (example - /add), the session would go away. After some searching on SO, I found an answer which solved my problem temporarily. I enabled "allow third party cookies" on firefox, and sessions now work.

Other details:
I am still running on localhost. 
Flask 0.7.
Firefox 8.
Iframe app. Not using the python SDK yet. Processing signed_request.

**What is the proper way of using sessions/cookies in facebook app?**

1. P3P headers? I saw this in [run with friends](https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends/) example
2. I am supposed to add some js method from Facebook javascript SDK, which ajaxifies all my requests?
3. is there some setting on FB app advanced panel to handle this?
4. Am I setting the cookie path incorrectly?